# $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos2\pi x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\mathrm{e}^{-\pi\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Can somebody help me out with the following integral?

Prove that:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{cos2\pi x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\frac{-\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}e^{-\pi\sqrt{3}}$

I have already determined the singularities: $z=e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$  and $z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. These are poles of order one. But determining the integral with the residue theorem doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

For the first residue I find: $Res(f,z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{4z^3+2z}$  (with z the first value above) and for the second in the same way.

Comment: Which contour did you use?

Comment: A half circle (above the real axis)

Comment: It must be some kind of a calculation error on your part. I used the same contour, computed the residues at the same points, and it's giving me the desired result. Maybe you can show us more of your work? What you got for the residues, and what you got for the final answer might help us figure out what went wrong.

Comment: See [example II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $\cos$ is even, and $\sin$ odd, so

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (2\pi x)}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (2\pi x)}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{e^{2\pi ix}}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx.$$

> For the first residue I find: $Res(f,z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{4z^3+2z}$  (with z the first value above) and for the second in the same way.

You forgot the factor $2\pi$ in the exponent, the residue is

$$\frac{e^{2\pi iz}}{4z^3 + 2z}.$$

Comment: This was something I already had. The further calculation goes wrong.

Comment: You should have written that in the question. What goes wrong and where?

Comment: The residuem theorem says that the integral must be equal to the sum of the residues of the singularities times 2pi*i. But my calculations don't lead to the given answer. I have considered the singularities in a half circle.

Comment: That sounds correct so far. Did you perhaps forget the factor $1/2$? With that, you need to compute $\pi i$ times the sum of the two residues in the upper half-plane. In any case, what result did you get?

Comment: @RoosJansen Simple mistake, you forgot the factor $2\pi$ in the exponent, see update.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^4+x^2+1=0\iff x_{1,2}^2=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt3\,i}2\implies\begin{cases}x_{1,2}=\pm\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)=\pm e^{\pi i/3}\\{}\\x_{3,4}=\pm\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)=\pm e^{2\pi i/3}\end{cases}$$

Taking

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{2\pi iz}}{z^4+z^2+1}\;,\;\;C_R=[-R,R]\cup\gamma_R:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;z=Re^{it}\;,\;R\in\Bbb R^+\;,\;0<t<\pi\}$$

We get that only the (simple) poles $\;x_1,x_3\;$ are within out contour's region, so

$$\begin{align*}\text{Res}_{z=x_1}(f)&=\lim_{z\to x_1}(z-x_1)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\frac{e^{\pi i(1+\sqrt3i)}}{-4+1+\sqrt3i}=-\frac{e^{\pi(-\sqrt 3+i)}}{3-\sqrt3i}\\{}\\
\text{Res}_{z=x_3}(f)&=\lim_{z\to x_3}(z-x_3)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\frac{e^{\pi i(-1+\sqrt3i)}}{4-1+\sqrt3i}=\frac{e^{\pi(-\sqrt 3-i)}}{3+\sqrt3i}\end{align*}$$

Try to take it from here.